# Execute a C program on a SHELL script

Tags: shell

I have a C program and a folder that contains files and I need to create a shell script that execute that C program and receives a file (one by one) name as argument which is read by the command line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following shell code :

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /PATH/TO/DIR
for i in *; do./C_APP "$i"; done
```